# Dictionaries python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I am making a dictionary , keys having 2 words.
Suppose I have two items in the dictionary:

```
{('am', 'and'): 1, ('and', 'am'): 1}
```

How to identify those above 2 keys are equal (they are just in different order).

```
for word1 in window:
    for word2 in window:
        if word1 != word2:
            word_pair_freq[(word1, word2)] += 1
```

I want the result

```
{('am', 'and'): 2}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to ignore the order of elements in a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755714/how-to-ignore-the-order-of-elements-in-a-tuple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the tuples to detect duplicate pairs:

```
my_dict = {('am', 'and'): 1, ('and', 'am'): 1}
word_pair_freq = {}
for words, value in my_dict.items():
    key = tuple(sorted(words))
    word_pair_freq[key] = word_pair_freq.get(key, 0) + value
print(word_pair_freq)
```

this will print

```
{('am', 'and'): 2}
```